# The argument type 'Stream<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to get document from firestore but i amm getting this following error

'''

```
onsearchBtnClick() async {``

isSearching = false;
//setState(() {});
usersStream = await DatabaseMethods()
    .getUserByUserName(searchUsernameEditingController.text);
//setState(() {});}


Widget searchUsersList() {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: usersStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              return Image.network(ds[index]);
            },
          )
        : Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
  },
);}Widget chatRoomsList() {
return Container();}
```

//database is

```
class DatabaseMethods {Future addUserInfoToDB(

  String userId, Map<String, dynamic> userInfoMap) async {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .set(userInfoMap);
```

}

{
Future<Stream> getUserByUserName(String username) async {

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .where("username", isEqualTo: username)
    .snapshots();
```

}
}

'''

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return type of `getUserByUserName` from `Future<Stream>` to `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`, and instead of assigning it to a new variable, use the `Stream` as it is `stream: DatabaseMethods().getUserByUserName(searchUsernameEditingController.text)`

Comment: after i changed like that i am getting these error: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?

Comment: i want to fletch the document from firestore using snapshot.data.doc

Answer (score 0):

You should remove await in

```
usersStream = await DatabaseMethods().getUserByUserName(searchUsernameEditingController.text);
```

If you put await for snapshot, it isn't a stream anymore.

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .where("username", isEqualTo: username)
    .snapshots();
```